# Set custom accessibilityIdentifier for GMSMarker

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use a Google Maps Api for maps and markers.

I enable accessibility for markers by setting: `mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false`

Now all my custom markers on map have accessibility ids like: `myappname.GMSPlaceMarker_somenumbers`, for example `myappname.GMSPlaceMarker_0x600000170200`.

How could i set a one `accessibilityIdentifier` for all pins, for example `Map pin`?

I already tried:

- `marker.accessibilityLabel = "Map pin"` but it set `label` value, not `id`
- `marker.title = "Map pin"` nothing changes
- `marker.setValue("Map pin", forKey: "accessibilityIdentifier")` nothing changes

My `marker` is `let marker = GMSPlaceMarker()` where `class GMSPlaceMarker: GMSMarker`

Comment: did you find a way to set accessibilityidentifier for the marker?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
func markPoints() {
    var annotationCoord : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    annotationCoord.latitude = (selectedLocation.latitude as NSString).doubleValue
    annotationCoord.longitude = (selectedLocation.longitude as NSString).doubleValue

    let annotationPoint: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord
    annotationPoint.title = selectedLocation.name
    annotationPoint.subtitle = "Anand: 7348858742"
    theMap.addAnnotation(annotationPoint)
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some description along with the code

Comment: Where is the accessibility id?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **swift 4** try this one,

```
    var destionationMarker: GMSMarker!

    func setupDriverMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {            
        destionationMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        for pin: GMSMarker in self.DestinationMarkerArray {
            if pin.userData as! String == "drivermarker" {
                pin.map = nil
            }
        }            
        destionationMarker.title = "Your Title"
        destionationMarker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        let images = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_map_marker")
        destionationMarker.icon = images
        destionationMarker.userData = "drivermarker"
        destionationMarker.opacity = 1
        destionationMarker.map = journeyMapView

    }
```

Implementing like this

```
DriverLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 21.2362546, longitude: 72.8751862)
setupDriverMarker(coordinate: DriverLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue as well, there is no accessibilityIdentifier for GMSMarker. What I did, setting either an accessibilityIdentifier to icon or iconView such as:

```
marker.icon?.accessibilityIdentifier = "something" or
marker.iconView?.accessibilityIdentifier = "something"
```

Answer (score 0):

set identifier like below (No access for accessibilityIdentifier)

```
marker.accessibilityLabel = "markerPinId"
```

read it in UITest

```
var element = app.buttons["markerPinId"]
```

make sure to add [accessibilityElementsHidden = false] as well